# Sending emails with outlook using Python and HTML

Tags: python, html, email, outlook, win32com

How do I successfully use a sender account with a password that is not already signed in to on the Outlook application on my laptop? I want to send a message from the example account, "from@outlook.com" but it has a password. I have this password. Am I able to enter this into the existing code?

```
import win32com.client as client
import datetime,time
outlook=client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
message=outlook.Createitem(0)
namespace=outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
inbox=namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
message=inbox.items.add
message.To="to@outlook.com"
message.CC=""
message.BCC=""
From = "from@outlook.com"
#password = ""

message.Subject="Subject text here"


message.BodyFormat = 2
message.HTMLBody = "<html><h2><span style='color:red'>There is an error with the file </b></span></h2> <body>Please check your submission and try again </body></html>"
message.Save()
message.Display()
time.sleep(5)

message.Send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `MailItem` object does not expose the `From` property. It exposes read-only `Sender` / `SenderEmailAddress` / `SenderName` properties, but they obviously cannot be set. You can set the `MailItem.Account` property to an instance of the `Account` object retrieved from the `Application.Session.Accounts` collection, but that requires you to configure the relevant account in Outlook first.

As a general rule, Outlook wont' let you send from an arbitrary one-off account not previously configured in Outlook.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to set the MailItem.Account property? I have signed into a second account in my outlook application and would like to try using this account as the sender

Comment: Do you mean second profile (as show in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profile)? Or second account in your default Outlook profile (as shown in the list of accounts when you hit the Form button in the Outlook email editor?